# Expression Language skip identifier check in tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I got following error :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.el.ELException: The identifier [case] is not a valid Java identifier as required by section 1.19 of the EL specification (Identifier ::= Java language identifier). This check can be disabled by setting the system property org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK to true.
```

It is due to in tomcat 7 by default SKIP IDENTIFIER CHECK feature is false(which was true in tomcat 6 and below) and I use "case" in regular expression and **case** is identifier so it throws error.

I found following solution:
[javax.el.ELException: The identifier [return] is not a valid Java identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233473/javax-el-elexception-the-identifier-return-is-not-a-valid-java-identifier)

But it would not work for me because I don't want to make changes in my code. So I want solution to configure tomcat 7 to SKIP IDENTIFIER CHECK to true.

Even after lots of googling I didn't find way to do this. I am using eclipse juno and tomcat 7, please help me regard this.

Comment: I think you need to brute-force the fix.  Personally, I would do a file search for all .jsp files containing the offending text.  Then I would use the search results to systematically replace each and every instance with the proper param['myParam'] version.  Lastly, I would re-run the file search to ensure I didn't miss any.  I have re-factored code like this in the past, and once you get a rhythm it usually goes pretty fast.

Comment: Yes @CodeChimp, it is my last option, but I need to change it in some of modules of my project as now I have no time to do that, this error come because I change my tomcat 6 to tomcat 7. I want solution as described in my question.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution.  You are using a key word, which is technically wrong to begin with.  Tomcat 7 just seemed to close the door on the problem.  Your choice is to spend an hour doing search-and-replace or back up to TC6 again.

Comment: Refer this http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html , in document they have specified that parameter, I want to know where I have to set this parameter.

Comment: I would guess catalina.properties, since its the only property file that comes to mind in Tomcat.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally got solution for eclipse. Add below line to the location I specify

```
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true
```

Please look for below step by step images

```
STEP 1 :
```

[image: Step 1]

```
STEP 2 :
```

[image: Step 2]

```
STEP 3 :
```

[image: Step 3]

Cheers. :)

Answer (score 5):

Create a setenv.[bat|sh] file in CATALINA_HOME/bin (i.e. alongside all your other scripts) and set the system property in that file. On Windows you'd create setenv.bat with the following contents:

```
SET CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true
```

On Linux you'd create setenv.sh with the following contents:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true"
```

You can repeat those lines (changing the system property name) to set multiple system properties in the same setenv.[bat|sh] file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using windows and my tomcat is at the D:/Tomcat 7/ location, can you please tell where have to create this bat file? In Config folder or where?

Comment: I had created bat file in bin directory as you specified but still i am getting same "javax.el.ELException" error

Answer (score 2):

We can also add following command to catalina.sh file under the tomcat_home dir/bin

CATALINA_OPTS="-Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while migrating my present application to Tomcat 7 it is(jsf 1.2 with ice faces 1.8.2). I have solved it by including a bat file with name setenv.bat with the below 
content in it.
'SET CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dorg.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true'

i have included it in TomcatInstallationDirectory/bin.

it is read by catalina.bat file. in the below line
'call "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat"'.

Hence my jspx pages are rendered appropriately

I had went through the following documentation by tomcat:

### https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt

please do post all the solution you made

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, for example, you have to add the folowing line to catalina.properties in Servers folder, (look for it in Package Explorer, and select your corresponding Tomcat folder):

```
org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK=true
```

Remember that Eclipse uses different location for configurations rather CATALINA original directories.

It's worthy to take a look on Tomcat's properties page, at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html