# How do I populate hidden form field with a value set in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

All,

I have a controller action in Spring MVC. This action is setting an attribute. I want this attribute to be set as a hidden value in the form.

Here's my controller action:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginForm(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) 
    {
        //URL to redirect the User to after Authentication
        String gotoUrl = request.getParameter("goto");

        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        model.addAttribute("gotoUrl", gotoUrl);
        model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
        return "loginform";
    }
```

In the JSP Form, I want something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="goto" id="goto" value="${gotoUrl}" />
```

But, this is not valid syntax according to JSP. Can you please suggest the valid syntax?

Thanks,

This is the stacktrace error:

```
javax.el.ELException: The identifier [gotoUrl] is not a valid Java identifier as required by section 1.19 of the EL specification (Identifier ::= Java language identifier). This check can be disabled by setting the system property org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK to true.
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.setImage(AstIdentifier.java:132)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Identifier(ELParser.java:1215)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.NonLiteral(ELParser.java:1191)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.ValuePrefix(ELParser.java:1017)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Value(ELParser.java:966)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Unary(ELParser.java:948)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Multiplication(ELParser.java:712)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Math(ELParser.java:632)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Compare(ELParser.java:444)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Equality(ELParser.java:338)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.And(ELParser.java:282)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Or(ELParser.java:226)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Choice(ELParser.java:183)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.Expression(ELParser.java:175)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.DynamicExpression(ELParser.java:147)
    org.apache.el.parser.ELParser.CompositeExpression(ELParser.java:44)
    org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:116)
    org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:172)
    org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:217)
    org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:67)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:984)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.loginform_jsp._jspService(loginform_jsp.java:176)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: Can you post the validation error?

Comment: It doesn't change anything, but why are using both `addAttribute` and `put`. All `addAttribute` does is check for null. Be consistent. And also, show us the exception from JSP.

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal: Please see my edit above for the stack trace

Comment: Can you use any other word than `goto`? Seems EL complains about java keywords.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233473/javax-el-elexception-the-identifier-return-is-not-a-valid-java-identifier or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900044/expression-language-skip-identifier-check-in-tomcat-7

Comment: Thanks all ! I renamed goto to gotoMyUrl and it worked..

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : Thanks. But why did you recommend to remove "put"?

Comment: @Jake A `ModelMap` extends `LinkedHashMap` which is a `Map` and has the `put` method. It's recommended to use the `addAttribute` method instead because it does a `null` check on the key first, throwing an error. If it's not `null`, it calls `put` internally.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ah.. I see.. Thank you very much. I am a newbie to Spring MVC. So, still learning.. :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the 'goto' name and id in

`<input type="hidden" name="goto" id="goto" value="${gotoUrl}" />`

and then match the new name, replacing 'goto' in

`request.getParameter("goto");`

Answer (score -1):

Set in body tag like this :

```
<body onload="
   $('#goto').val('
    <c:if test="${gotoValueFromModel ne null}">
    <c:out value="${gotoValueFromModel}"/>
    </c:if>');
                     '
             " 
> 

   <form:form>
     <form:hidden  accesskey="goto" id="goto" path="goto" />
   </form:form>
```